# Regular expression in Search Sharepoint 2013

Tags: regex, search, sharepoint, expression

I have problem to use regular expression at Sharepoint 2013 Search.
I insert it into crawl rule and checked Use regular expression syntax for matching this rule.

I valid my regex on page regex101 so I am sure at 100% it is right.

```
^(https?:\/\/)([\da-zA-z\.]+)\/([\da-zA-z]+)$
```

This is on the first place of craw rules and I select exclude, but pages are still searchable.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Perhaps, the input URLs are still matched? Could you add examples? And a link to your regex101 try would be helpful.

Comment: https://regex101.com
Copy my regex and example is 'https://gooogle.pl/test'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please pay attention that according to [MSDN blogs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/enterprisesearch/archive/2010/01/21/regular-expressions-support-in-crawl-rules.aspx) (though it is for MS SharePoint 2010, I think it is still valid for 2013, too)

> Regular expression operators cannot be used in the protocol part of
>   the URL. This means, for example, the following RegEx rule cannot be
>   created: .*//www.microsoft.com/.* If you try to create a rule like
>   this, the system will add http:// in the beginning and thus make “.*”
>   as the second part of the URL. The resulting rule in this case will
>   be: http:// .*//www.microsoft.com/.* which may not be what you
>   intended.

So, try just `([\da-zA-Z.]+)\/([\da-zA-Z]+)$`.

Or even `([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)$`